# Limit of parametric definite integral with discontinuity

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

How to find this limit?

$$
I = \lim_{t \to 0+0} \int_1^3 \frac{\sin(tx)}{t} \sqrt{x^2 + t^2 + tx + 1} dx
$$

The problem is that it is impossible to make the limit transition
$$
I = \int_1^3 \lim_{t \to 0+0} \frac{\sin(tx)}{t} \sqrt{x^2 + t^2 + tx + 1} dx,
$$
because the integrand function has a discontinuity in $t = 0$, therefore, the previous statement is incorrect, generally speaking.

Comment: what do you mean from $t \rightarrow 0+0 $?

Comment: @darya-khosrotash, one-sided limit, $t \to 0$ and $t > 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\sin(t\,x)}{t}=x\,\frac{\sin(t\,x)}{t\,x}=x\,\text{sinc}(t\,x),
$$
and the function
$$
\text{sinc}(z)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin z}{z} & z\ne0\\
1 & z=0
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous.